# SQL merge multiple statements with different JOINs

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Hi I've tried to merge those 3 statements into 1 statement with the following result set (grouped by the company_name):

- company_name
- employees (count)
- activities (count)
- projects (count)

the statements all by one work fine.

```
SELECT c.NAME AS company_name,
    COUNT(c2.ID) AS employees
FROM contact c
    JOIN relation r ON c.ID = r.FID
    JOIN contact c2 ON r.CID = c2.ID
WHERE c.TYPE = 'ORG'
    AND c2.TYPE = 'PRS'
GROUP BY c.NAME;

SELECT c.NAME AS company_name,
    COUNT(c3.ID) AS activities
FROM contact c
    JOIN relation r ON c.ID = r.FID
    JOIN activity c3 ON r.CID = c3.ID
WHERE c.TYPE = 'ORG'
GROUP BY c.NAM;

SELECT c.NAME AS company_name,
    COUNT(c4.ID) AS projects
FROM contact c
    JOIN relation r ON c.ID = r.CID
    JOIN project c4 ON r.FID = c4.ID
WHERE c.TYPE = 'ORG'
GROUP BY c.NAM;
```

my result should look like this combination:[image: result columns]

Here is what worked the best so far but still it's not correct yet:

```
SELECT c.NAME AS company_name,
    COUNT(
        CASE
            WHEN c2.TYPE = 'PRS' THEN c2.ID
        END
    ) AS employees,
    COUNT(c3.ID) AS activities,
    COUNT(c4.ID) AS projects
FROM contact c
    JOIN relation r ON c.ID = r.FID
    LEFT JOIN contact c2 ON r.CID = c2.ID
    AND c2.TYPE = 'PRS'
    LEFT JOIN activity c3 ON r.CID = c3.ID
    LEFT JOIN project c4 ON r.FID = c4.ID
WHERE c.TYPE = 'ORG'
GROUP BY c.NAME;
```

Comment: `with subquery1 as (<whatever SELECT query you have>), subquery2 as (<another SELECT query you have), subquery3 as (), ... select * from subquery1 full join subquery2 using(company_name) full join subquery3 using(company_name)`

Comment: This is a strange data model. Isn't there at least a column to indicate which table a relation relates to? As is, you must somehow ensure that the tables contact, activity and project have different IDs.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner It may be the model based on sort of inheritance, where each of `contact`, `activity` and `project` is a subclass of some general `object`. But such model *generally* has some sort of relation type column, so it's unclear what may be wrong with the current code since ID do not clutter and are unique (or do they really `ID`entify an instance?). Anyway the question should include some sample data to demonstrate what is *not correct yet*

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate before joining so that each relation joins to at most one (aggregated) row for each set of employees, activities and projects (which will prevent you getting issues of double-counting if you were taking the cross-product of result sets with multiple matching rows) and then in the outer query you can `SUM` the pre-aggregated values to get the final total:

```sql
SELECT MAX(c.NAME) AS company_name,
       COALESCE(SUM(e.employees), 0) AS employees,
       COALESCE(SUM(a.activities), 0) AS activities,
       COALESCE(SUM(p.projects), 0) AS projects
FROM   contact c
       INNER JOIN relation r
       ON c.ID = r.FID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
           SELECT id,
                  COUNT(id) AS employees
           FROM   contact
           WHERE  TYPE = 'PRS'
           GROUP BY id
       ) e
       ON (r.CID = e.ID)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
           SELECT id,
                  COUNT(id) AS activities
           FROM   activity
           GROUP BY id
       ) a
       ON (r.CID = a.ID)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
           SELECT id,
                  COUNT(id) AS projects
           FROM   project
           GROUP BY id
       ) p
       ON (r.FID = p.ID)
WHERE  c.TYPE = 'ORG'
GROUP BY c.ID;
```

*Note: you can also `GROUP BY` the unique identifier for each company, rather than the name, to prevent results being erroneously aggregated when there are two companies with the same name.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query if it works.

```
SELECT 
    c.NAME AS company_name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN c2.TYPE = 'PRS' THEN c2.ID END) AS employees,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN c3.ID IS NOT NULL THEN c3.ID END) AS activities,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN c4.ID IS NOT NULL THEN c4.ID END) AS projects
FROM contact c
LEFT JOIN relation r ON c.ID = r.FID
LEFT JOIN contact c2 ON r.CID = c2.ID AND c2.TYPE = 'PRS'
LEFT JOIN activity c3 ON r.CID = c3.ID
LEFT JOIN project c4 ON r.FID = c4.ID
WHERE c.TYPE = 'ORG'
GROUP BY c.NAME;
```